# How does proxylist sites discover new proxy?

Tags: proxy, http-proxy, socks5

I always got proxies from proxylist websites but I never asked me how these sites discover new proxy. So how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking over ProxyFire it seems like a good option. Although, I prefer using protocols rather than programs. So, looking through the features of ProxyFire, it performs some port scanning which Nmap can supply. [Socks proxy servers scanning with Nmap](https://funoverip.net/2010/11/socks-proxy-servers-scanning-with-nmap/).

Above I described how to discover SOCKS proxy servers by port scanning. Another, option would be looking through forums where users dump lists of SOCKS proxies. See, [My-Proxy Forum](https://forum.my-proxy.com/).

Alternatively, the websites may host the proxies themselves. Either by servers volunteered to them, physical servers owned by them, or using data centre VPSs.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, these sites have admins or people that work for the site. I know a person that works for these kind of sites and he said he uses a proxy scraper like ProxyFire and other ones.